# PhpSpreadsheet foreach loop through multiple sheets

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm new to PhpSpreadsheet, I have a file with multiple sheets (all the same), I checked all the examples in the [Reader](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-files/#reading-files) section of the documentation, but each example ends with a code like

```
$sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

so seems that I can get my data only from the active sheet.
I would like to loop through each sheet to get data from each one, something like:

```
foreach ($sheetData as $sheet) { 
    echo "...my data ...";
}
```

Any idea? Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'd want to use the `getSheetCount()` method to determine how many sheets there are, and then use a standard `for` loop with `getSheet()`:

```
$sheetCount = $spreadsheet->getSheetCount();
for ($i = 0; $i < $sheetCount; $i++) {
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet($i);
    $sheetData = $sheet->toArray(null, true, true, true);
}
```

See the [Worksheet documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/worksheets/).

Comment: I will read more deeply next time. Thanks for answering and pointing me in the right direction.